# Centralised Environment variables

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, openshift, devops

I am looking for a tool which can help to maintain the environment variables and their values in a centralised location and used by many applications from the centralised location.

For example, I have a environment variable called API_KEY and the value of API_KEY in UAT environment for specific service will be same and I want the application to fetch the value of API_KEY from a tool.

Please share your thoughts if you have come across similar tools.

Thanks and Regards!!!
Ananth Francis.

Comment: Have you checked hashicorp vault https://www.vaultproject.io/

Comment: There are a lot of similar things depending on what your setup, as stated above Hashicorp Valut is awesome, however if you don't mind changing code you could get the same result with any kind of DB, or alternatively you could use Managed services (I Know azure has a secrets vault)

Comment: Thanks @Spazzy757
We tried installing vault in our openshift since vault requires root ID to run the container. Due to security reason, we are not allowed to use root id eventhough we have work around in openshift.

Comment: Thanks @mchawre for your response

Comment: Have you tried maybe just running a Redis instance in cluster and using that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [ConfigMaps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/configmap).

> ConfigMaps bind configuration files, command-line arguments,
>   **environment variables**, port numbers, and other configuration artifacts
>   to your Pods' containers and system components at runtime.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) is an official documentation describing how to use it.

> ConfigMaps are useful for storing and sharing non-sensitive,
>   unencrypted configuration information. To use sensitive information in
>   your clusters, you must use [Secrets](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret).

Analogically here you can find more info about [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Configmap and secrets will be used by only one namespace. But, I want to store the variables which will be used by multiple applications.

Comment: Workaround for this would be to copy it over, for example with the following command:
`kubectl get secret <secret-name> — namespace=<source-namespace>  -o yaml | sed ‘s/namespace: <from-namespace>/namespace: <to-namespace>/’ | kubectl create -f`

Comment: Sorry OhHiMark.
Unfortunately, we can not use the work around you suggested. Above work around will create a source namespace secret in target namespace. But, we would like to find a product/tool which will store both secrets and env variables and inject the only required env variables. We are planning to try vault for this.
Thank you very much for your suggestions.